# Селекторы в дискорде через пайтон

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Всем привет, весь день угробил на гуглёж но постоянно код через ошибки писал, **очень прошу скинуть шаблончик селектора с любым (Для примера средним) текстом ну т.е что-то такое**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поскольку кода в вопросе нет, что не работает с [примером из документации](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#select-menu-types-select-menu-example)?